# CMake add_definitions with string fails on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

My problem is following: in CMakeLists.txt I add line:

```
add_definitions(-DPROJECT_ROOT="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../..")
```

When I try to use PROJECT_ROOT in source code I can not build it.
It says

```
error: expected expression
    std::cout << PROJECT_ROOT;
                 ^
expanded from here
#define PROJECT_ROOT "<correct value>"
```

I have tried the very same thing on Linux and it worked well. Could anyone, please, suggest anything?
I am using CMake and g++ on OS X 10.10.

Comment: Which versions of CMake do/did you run on OS X and Linux?

Comment: @zenith 3.2.3 on OS X and 3.3.1 on Linux

Comment: @zenith I have just tried upgrading to 3.3.1 on OS X. It did not help.